# button ignores parent div and won't align

Tags: html, css

I can't quite get to the bottom of this: it seems that my parent div is being ignored by the browser when I want to align it. Hopefully any of you guys can get it! Thanks!

This is my parent div:

```
#button-subheading {
height: auto;
width: auto;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

and this is my child:

```
 .button, button {
    color: #fff !important;
    font-size: -63px;
    font-family: "CentraleSans-Bold","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
    line-height: 265%;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #167de4;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    border: 1px solid #1d4ea4;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.23),inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.19);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 100%, 50% 0%, color-stop(0%, #3669ef), color-stop(100%, #4f95f4));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #3669ef 0%,#4f95f4 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #3669ef 0%,#4f95f4 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #3669ef 0%,#4f95f4 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #3669ef 0%,#4f95f4 100%);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

when I try to implement it trough this HTML it gets stuck on the left of the screen:

```
    <div id="button-subheading">
        <div class="button" href="#" style="opacity: 1;">Get started with a free 30-day trial</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: stuck at the right on the screen? does not seem like: http://jsfiddle.net/hppXY/.
Maybe you could tell us, what youre trying to archieve?

Comment: Works for me too ..http://jsfiddle.net/DswL2/

Comment: I think we'll need more context of what you're trying to do and more html.

Comment: oops typo! I meant the left, fixed now. I want it to be in the middle of the screen though, can't get it there no matter what :(. It's important to get a nice alignment, but this thing won't work :(

Comment: I want it to align in the center, it shouldn't matter, but it's wrapped in this container:  '  #container  {
width: 100%;
height: 90%; 
background: #ef6957;
font-family: biko;
margin: auto;
background-image: url('header.jpg');
background-repeat: no repeat;
background-size: 100%;
} '

Comment: You have to give a specific width to one of the div's. then you can do left: 50% on second div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already a couple answers here, and even a chosen one. But I suppose I'll share my alternate solution anyways, so there are even more options available to you.

The way I solved with was by changing one line of CSS under the .button, button styles, turning `position:absolute` to `display:inline-block`. Absolute positioning can be very difficult to properly work into a layout, since it basically removes the element from the "flow" of the HTML.

Also, another minor thing I think might be helpful to you, is to use an anchor (a) element for the button, rather than a div, since clicking on an anchor would actually bring you to the specified href.

Here's a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RgGHW/

Regardless though, glad you got an answer to your question!

Comment: Thanks! Great solution! Works even better with me :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help you out. Good luck web developing!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to place only that element into the center, this could be a way to go:

```
#button-subheading {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -150px; /* half the width of your element */
  margin-top: -150px;  /* half the height of your element */
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hppXY/2/)

Comment: That's amazing! Thanks! Now, just for my understanding; what was your reason of thought so from now on I can handle this myself again? ;-)

Comment: it depends of what you are trying to achieve. In different situations you use different `position` and nesting of divs. In your case you can keep it simple with `position: absolute`. As other answers say, this solution might be not so good, if you have a layout which has more elements and they're building up together!

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning can get a bit annoying, i'm assuming you have a container div with a pixel width.
Just set a width on the container (`button-sub heading`) then set a width and auto margin on the `button`. The button will center in its container.

You have to have a width set on elements you want to center with `margin:auto`

Here is rough example: **http://jsfiddle.net/hppXY/4/**